# How to return Promise<Type> when value to return is of type Promise<Type | null>? Typescript server

Tags: typescript, server

I'm trying to return a user of type UserRecord after saving to database, but getting a linting error because `getUserByUuid` returns `Promise<UserRecord | null>` so the linter is returning an error because I'm trying to return a type `<UserRecord | null>` for `createUser` which returns `Promise<UserRecord>`.  I've tried to type assert it `user!` but it's not working.
I'm checking it in the null check right before the return but the linter isn't picking it up.
What's the best way to handle this situation?

```
  createUser = async (params: any): Promise<UserRecord> => {
    try {
      
      await insertUser(params);
      const user = this.getUserByUuid(params.uuid);
      if (user === null) {
        throw new Error("user failed to save");
      }
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you return a Promise, which is never going to be `null`, for your code to work you need to await `getUserByUuid`

```
const user = this.getUserByUuid(params.uuid);//user is Promise<UserRecord|null>
```

vs

```
const user = await this.getUserByUuid(params.uuid);//user is UserRecord|null - this should work
```

Comment: Thanks! Totally missed that!